# Android ignore case when sorting list

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections, case-insensitive

I have a List named path I'm currently sorting my strings with the following code

```
  java.util.Collections.sort(path);
```

That is working fine it sorts my list however it treats the cases of the first letter differently that is it sorts the list with upper-case letters and then sorts the list with lower-case letters after so if I had the following cat dog Bird Zebra it would sort it like

```
Bird
Zebra
dog
cat
```

so how do I ignore case so that dog and cat would come before Zebra but after Bird?
Thank you for any help

Comment: Just for your information SO has stated new android site. Check it out here: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This really is a general Java question, not Android specific.

Comment: thanks didn't know about android site guess i should move there since all i do is android stuff just starting to get acquainted with java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom comparator class:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

class IgnoreCaseComparator implements Comparator<String> {
  public int compare(String strA, String strB) {
    return strA.compareToIgnoreCase(strB);
  }
}
```

Then on your sort:

```
IgnoreCaseComparator icc = new IgnoreCaseComparator();

java.util.Collections.sort(path,icc);
```

Comment: ended up using this and it worked great going to try the other solution as well but gave this the check cause this was the one i tried first and it worked thanks for the help from both of you

Answer (score 11):

Use the built-in String comparator String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER

```
java.util.Collections.sort(path, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Collections.sort(path,new Comparator<String>(){
   public int compare(String strA, String strB) {
    return strA.compareToIgnoreCase(strB);
  }
});
```